# Using NodeJS for Google searching, can I prompt for reCAPTCHA when it comes up? (Puppeteer/Cheerio)

Tags: javascript, node.js, recaptcha, cheerio, puppeteer

I am writing a somewhat simple web scraper that uses Puppeteer to search Google for a list of queries.

I have it working until I hit Google's reCAPTCHA. I know bypassing reCAPTCHA is unorthodox so I won't ask for something like that here (although the code I'm using was an attempt at that -- sorry, not sorry).

What I'm hoping for is some kind of prompt to enter the reCAPTCHA when it comes up so I can continue searching.

I'm new to Node so if perhaps PhantomJS or something similar would be better for what I'm trying to accomplish I'm willing to rewrite it from the ground up. I haven't tried because Phantom seems so much messier and there's less documentation on it.

Anyway, my code follows:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const LineByLine = require('line-by-line'),
    lr = new LineByLine('dorks.txt', {skipEmptyLines: true});

   ---- snip ----

lr.on('end', async function () {
    console.log(`[*] Loaded ${dorks.length+1} dorks. Let's begin.`);
    for (var i = 0; i < dorks.length; i++) {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({timeout: 10000, headless: false});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        try {
            await page.goto('https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=' + dorks[i]);
            let content = await page.content();
            var $ = cheerio.load(content);

            if (content.includes("Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network.")) {
                // call captcha handler?
                console.log(`We got CAPTCHA'd. -_-`);
                await $('form').contents().find('textarea#g-recaptcha-response').html(key); // this acts like it works but doesn't
                await $('form').contents().find('input#recaptcha-token').val(key); // this one isn't even trying
                // This is probably an issue with recaptcha being in an iFrame but I'm lost
                await page.click('[name="submit"]');
                await page.waitForNavigation();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
});

---- snip ----
```

Sorry for the wall of text. This is the first time I've come to a forum for help like this and I didn't want to give too little info.

Send help.

Edit: Snipped out a bunch of code so no one has to wade through it.  Updated title. Hopefully it wasn't better before. First post guys, sorry.

Comment: Hi Chase, I see you've already turned off headless mode. Maybe slowing puppeteer down for debugging purposes will reveal what exactly is happening in the browser? See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#debugging-tips.

Comment: I am completely aware of what's happening in the browser. Google asks me to complete a captcha before being redirected to my results... I want to prompt for the captcha when running in headless mode...

Comment: If you're looking for a better, more interactive way to debug I'd say check out https://chrome.browserless.io/, which will show you + open up a debugger for you.